# AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'getPixel'

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm following the Automate the Boring Stuff book tutorial on automation and in this exercise I'm trying to get the color of a certain pixel on a image I screenshotted. Here is some of the code:

```
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        pixelColor = pyautogui.screenshot().getPixel((x, y))
```

The code above is identical to the one in the book, but I keep getting the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'getPixel'`

I assumed that I was importing the wrong library or something, but it seems like that isn't the problem. Here's what I'm importing:

```
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image
```

How can I solve this bug?

Comment: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpixel ... look at the spelling of that method.

Comment: Oh boy, didn't notice that. Now it worked just fine, thanks a lot!

Comment: You could Vote to Close as Off-Topic for Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is right the pillow image object does not have attribute getPixel,
Try

```
 pixelColor = pyautogui.screenshot().getpixel((x, y))
```